# Using & (bitwise AND operator) in Angular ng-if expressions

Tags: javascript, angularjs, syntax, bitwise-operators, and-operator

I can't get the `&` operator to work in an Angular `ng-if` expression (to use with some bit flags). Suppose we have some HTML like this:

```
<div ng-if="value & 2"> </div>
```

If `value` equals 3, then the bitwise operation should return 2 and thus a true value.

However, Angular throws a `Syntax Error` exception every time. Is the operation not allowed? Or am I doing something wrong?

Link to the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Yz2qESo1dSGp35O1dxm8?p=preview).

Edit: I already resolved my issue by using a simple function that does the job:

```
$scope.checkFlag = function(value, flag){
   return value & flag;
}
```

But I really don't like this solution. Is there a way to use it in an `ng-if` (without using the function, obviously)?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You cannot use the bitwise `&` operator in an Angular expression. According to the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression):

> Angular expressions are like JavaScript expressions with the following differences:
>
> - ...
> - You cannot use Bitwise, `,` or `void` operators in an Angular expression.
>
> If you want to run more complex JavaScript code, you should make it a controller method and call the method from your view.

A note on nomenclature: `&` is the **bitwise** AND operator; `&&` is the **logical** AND operator.

**UPDATE:** Your `checkFlag` function is probably the best workaround because its name makes it clear what it does (and that's what I would use), but if you *absolutely* don't want an extra function, you can use the following equivalent expression:

```
<div ng-if="value % 4 >= 2"> </div>
```

In general, `(value & x) != 0` (where `x` is a power of 2) is equivalent to `value % (2 * x) >= x`.

Answer (score 4):

One can accomplish this with a bitwise pipe:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'hasFlags'
})
export class HasFlagsPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(flagsL: number, flagsR: number): boolean {
    return (flagsL & flagsR) != 0;
  }

}
```

Usage:

```
<div [hidden]="flagsL | hasFlags : flagsR">
```

Note: I'm using angular 2+ but came across this post so hopefully this helps someone else.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're using `&` instead of `&&`. `&` is the bitwise operator, and Angular doesn't allow bitwise operators in expressions.

Comment: I'd assume he is in fact trying to use the bit wise operator so I don't know if your first sentence is true. Unless && somehow mimics that behavior in angular and I'm an idiot.

Comment: Yeah, i am trying to use *specifically* the bitwise operation. I want to use the bitwise operation in order to handle my bit flags.

Comment: Ah, I see. Well, as Michael and Vilius have shown, Angular doesn't allow bitwise in their expressions.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you want to accomplish here but you are using a bit-wise AND operator. And in the angular documentation it says:

> No Bitwise, Comma, And Void Operators: You cannot use Bitwise, , or void operators in an Angular expression.

[AngularJS expression](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression)

Answer (score 1):

Since no one has provided a solution I'd assume you could just modify your html to:

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
   <div ng-if="check(value,2)">Hey! </div>
</body>
```

with

```
$scope.check = function(val, providedInt){
   return val & providedInt;
 };
```

[See plunkr!](http://plnkr.co/edit/RQwqQTyaDYpxRl3GgR6p?p=preview)